# Do unused imports in Flash Builder 4 affect RUNTIME performance?

Tags: apache-flex, optimization, flash-builder

*I have not found any links that referred to the `unused imports in Flash Builder`. There were, however, a plethora of links and comments on this subject for the more popular languages. 
I assume that ALL compilers optimize unused imports in the same manner but need to be sure before I pass this information on to my superior.*

So...**DO UNUSED IMPORTS AFFECT RUNTIME PERFORMANCE IN FLASH BUILDER PROJECTS???**

*Please provide references! 
Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2):

If the classes are not used in your code, the import statement will be ignored by the compiler and the classes will be NOT included in your compiled application. So the unused imports will have no effect on a compiled app at all.

I can't think of a reference but it was always like that in FB. You can test it yourself though - take an empty application, include some custom component to it and compile. Check the swf filesize. Then remove the component but leave the import in. Compile again and you will see that the filesize was reduced (this  component was not included in the app).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Brian